# Are there any missing resources in jbpm-server-7.22.0.Final-dist.zip

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to follow the getting started guide from https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStarted.html but I can not see some parts of the user interface.

I have downloaded jbpm-server-7.22.0.Final-dist.zip, extracted the content of this archive into C:\jbpm-server, and then run jbpm-server\bin\standalone.bat.
My operating system is Windows 7, and JAVA_HOME points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

When I access Business Central (http://localhost:8080/business-central) and log in as krisv/krisv, I can see the Welcome Page.
If I click on "Projets" under the "Design" section, the new page does not display any text neither in the combo located just under the "plus" sign, nor in the drop down menu located in the upper right corner, just under the login name.

I have a similar behavior when I access http://localhost:8080/jbpm-casemgmt : some text is missing.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I access the webpage, the locale is automatically detected and it seems that the i18n file for my locale "fr" is not fully defined.

I changed the locale directly in the url (http://localhost:8080/business-central/kie-wb.jsp?locale=en) and now it works.